# How i get a complete list with ALL eMails

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

i will get a simply list with all eMail which a have in my inbox - with settings "Conversation view off". My script currently looks like this:

```
function getAllMail(){
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox');
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var id = threads[i].getId();
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
    Logger.log(i);
    }
}
```

So i get a list with the view: "Conversation view on".

Where is my thinkingfault?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need something that will list all the threads or conversation in your inbox. Try to [manage threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads).

> The Gmail API uses [**`Thread` resources**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads) to group email replies
>   with their original message into a single conversation or thread. This
>   allows you to retrieve all messages in a conversation, in order,
>   making it easier to have context for a message or to refine search
>   results.

To retrieve threads, [here](http://Threads%20provide%20a%20simple%20way%20of%20retrieving%20messages%20in%20a%20conversation%20in%20order.%20By%20listing%20a%20set%20of%20threads%20you%20can%20choose%20to%20group%20messages%20by%20conversation%20and%20provide%20additional%20context.%20You%20can%20retrieve%20a%20list%20of%20threads%20using%20the%20threads.list%20method,%20or%20retrieve%20a%20specific%20thread%20with%20threads.get.%20You%20can%20also%20filter%20threads%20using%20the%20same%20query%20parameters%20as%20for%20the%20Message%20resource.%20If%20any%20message%20in%20a%20thread%20matches%20the%20query,%20that%20thread%20is%20returned%20in%20the%20result.) is what you need.

> Threads provide a simple way of retrieving messages in a conversation
>   in order. By listing a set of threads you can choose to group messages
>   by conversation and provide additional context. You can retrieve a
>   list of threads using the [**threads.list**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) method, or retrieve a specific
>   thread with [**threads.get**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list). You can also [filter threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) using the same
>   query parameters as for the [**`Message` resource**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages). If any message in a
>   thread matches the query, that thread is returned in the result.

You can study the sample codes provided in the [quickstart guides](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).

Comment: Hello, do you have a simply script-example for me?